# Stream error handling/fallback nodes

Tags: node.js, azure, stream

I am trying to use nodejs streams (first time using stream, so please bear with me) to fetch an image from cloud storage (azure blob storage).
In a get request I fetch the requested image file in a stream and want to stream this back to the client. If the image exists in the requested resolution in the blob storage I want to serve the image directly piping it back to the response. If the requested resolution does not exist I want to fetch the original image, resize it (passing it through a sharp() transform) and piping it back to the response. If the original image does not exist I want to get a fallback image and serve that thought the sharp transform etc.

Problem is that I want to put all this logic into a function that **returns a stream** (available for piping to other functions) rather that passing the target stream to which the result will be piped.
I also do not want to repeat the transformation logic for each different case over and over.

So far I did sth like:

```
if (!size) {
        return blobService
            .fetch(avatarId)
            .on('error', function (e) {
                logger.error({error: e}, 'avatar not found');
            })
    } else {
        return blobService
            .fetch(avatarId + '_s' + size)
            .on('error', function (e) {
                logger.info({err: e}, 'converted file not found');
                // TODO: this return does not work, thus not serving custom resized images
                return blobService
                    .fetch(avatarId)
                    .on('error', function (e) {
                        logger.error({err: e}, 'original file not found');
                    //TODO: if the original was not found then fetch a default image and serve that.
                    return blobService
                        .fetch(defaultId)
                        .on('error', function (e) {})
                        .pipe(sharp().resize(size, size)); //TODO: I should not have to repeat this (or 10 other steps) again and again
                    })
                    .pipe(sharp().resize(size, size));
            });
    }
```

Problem is return statements inside error handlers do nothing. I also tried declaring a duplex stream and using that in the logic paths and returning it at the end, but all I got returned was an empty stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your first `return blobService`, you send a reading stream to the writing stream. Problem is as soon as an error occurs on the readable stream it is closed and as a result your writing stream is also closed. That's why you always get empty data.

What you need is a duplex stream and write to it from your first `blobService`. In case an error occurs, don't close the duplex stream. Instead in the error callback start reading your second `blobService` and write to the duplex stream.

You can create a duplex stream from node's [`stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex) library. But for simplicity I'm giving an example using [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2):

```
var through = require('through2')

function imageService(){

  var duplex = through(function(chunk,enc,callback){
    this.push(chunk)
    callback()
  })

  blobService
    .fetch(avatarId + '_s' + size) // your first readable stream
    .on('error',function(){  // error on the first readable stream      
       blobService 
        .fetch(avatarId) //your second readable stream
        .on('error', function(){ //error on 2nd readable stream
           //do it again...
        })
        .pipe(duplex) //write your second readable stream
    })
    .pipe(duplex) // write your first readable stream

  return duplex;
}
```

Comment: Other than that I was using nodejs native stream module, I did something similar with the duplex stream, but wasn't working. Anyhow, I am now using through2 which from what I read has some advantages over native impl. and everything seems to work. Any idea if I could DRY my code if I have say 10 identical transforms that need to be applied to some of the streams? Is there a way of grouping transforms into a single function?

Comment: Look at these libraries : [fallback-stream](https://github.com/shinnn/fallback-stream) and [multistream](https://github.com/feross/multistream)

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value from a callback function. The function can end at any time so when you access to the return value the callback may not have finished.

If you wants to access to the return value, put the code that need the return value inside your callback. For example, this code:

```
var bar = new Bar();
function foo() {
   bar.baz(function() {
     return 2;
  }
}
var v1 = foo();  // v1 will be undefined
otherFunction(v1); // send undefined to otherFunction instead of 2
```

has to become:

```
var bar = new Bar();
function foo() {
   bar.baz(function() {
     otherFunction(2);
  }
}
foo();
```